# Sum Every N Records SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this query, which returns (Right Below 'Query Results') a grouped date(varchar), and some values.
They are vehicles that have passed by toll plazas.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CAB_MOMENTO,1,12),
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '1' AND NOME IN ('SUL','OESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
SUL_OESTE_AUTO,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '0' AND NOME IN ('SUL','OESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
SUL_OESTE_COM,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '1' AND NOME IN ('NORTE','LESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) NORTE_LESTE_AUTO,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '0' AND NOME IN ('NORTE','LESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) NORTE_LESTE_COM FROM
(SELECT a.idtransaccion, a.cab_momento, a.cab_via, a.comvsauto, b.NOME
FROM
(select idtransaccion, cab_momento, cab_via, cab_estacion AS ESTACION,
CASE ctl_clase
WHEN '01' THEN 1
WHEN '07' THEN 1
WHEN '08' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END comvsauto
FROM usrhost.atransaccion
WHERE cab_momento > '20170818000000') a
INNER join
(SELECT sen.estacion AS ESTACION, via.via AS VIA, sen.nome AS NOME FROM 
usrhost.aestacion_sentido sen
INNER JOIN usrhost.avia via ON
sen.estacion = via.estacion
AND SubStr(via.via,3,1) = sen.sentido
ORDER BY 1,2) b ON
b.VIA = a.cab_via
AND b.ESTACION = a.ESTACION)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CAB_MOMENTO,1,12)
ORDER BY 1
```

I need the sum every 15 minutes (1st column).

For example:
From minute X to Minute Y - 1231 | 12314 | 1241 | 21415
From minute X+15 to Minute Y+15 - 1111 | 13344 | 1345 | 22455
...

Thank You In Advance

[image: Query Results]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression below to give you a datetime with the minutes adjusted to quarter hours. This will give you the ability to easily group to times and dates.

```
CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(30), cab_momento, 126), 14) + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MINUTE, cab_momento) / 15 * 15), 2) + ':00.000', 126)
```

Answer (score 0):

Work it! Thank you very much.

```
SELECT SubStr(CAB_MOMENTO,1,10) ||' '||
   CASE WHEN To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 15 THEN '00-15'
        WHEN To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 30 THEN '15-30'
        WHEN To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 45 THEN '30-45'
        ELSE '45-00'
   END As time_period, Sum(sul_oeste_auto), 
Sum(sul_oeste_com),Sum(norte_leste_auto), Sum(norte_leste_com)
FROM (

SELECT SUBSTR(CAB_MOMENTO,1,12) AS cab_momento,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '1' AND NOME IN ('SUL','OESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
SUL_OESTE_AUTO,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '0' AND NOME IN ('SUL','OESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
SUL_OESTE_COM,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '1' AND NOME IN ('NORTE','LESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) NORTE_LESTE_AUTO,
Sum(CASE WHEN COMVSAUTO = '0' AND NOME IN ('NORTE','LESTE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END) NORTE_LESTE_COM FROM
(SELECT a.idtransaccion, a.cab_momento, a.cab_via, a.comvsauto, b.NOME
FROM
(select idtransaccion, cab_momento, cab_via, cab_estacion AS ESTACION,
CASE ctl_clase
WHEN '01' THEN 1
WHEN '07' THEN 1
WHEN '08' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END comvsauto
FROM usrhost.atransaccion
WHERE cab_momento > '20170818000000') a
INNER join
(SELECT sen.estacion AS ESTACION, via.via AS VIA, sen.nome AS NOME FROM 
usrhost.aestacion_sentido sen
INNER JOIN usrhost.avia via ON
sen.estacion = via.estacion
AND SubStr(via.via,3,1) = sen.sentido
ORDER BY 1,2) b ON
b.VIA = a.cab_via
AND b.ESTACION = a.ESTACION)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CAB_MOMENTO,1,12)
ORDER BY 1)
GROUP  BY SubStr(CAB_MOMENTO,1,10),CASE WHEN 
To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 15 THEN '00-15'
        WHEN To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 30 THEN '15-30'
        WHEN To_Number(SubStr(cab_momento,11,2)) < 45 THEN '30-45'
        ELSE '45-00'
   END
```

ORDER BY 1